# Nested conditionals in MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document structure that looks like:

```
{
   _id : <number>
   timestamp : <datetime>
   ...
}
```

I'm trying to do a query on a collection of such documents, where given a new `id`, and an associated `timestamp`, I do the following:

- Check if the new `id` already exists in the collection
- If `id` **does not** exist, then create a new document and add the new document with id and timestamp
- If `id` **does exist**, then for the document that matched, check the `timestamp`
- If the `timestamp` is older/smaller than the new one, then replace the old `timestamp` with the new one. Else, do nothing.

What I have currently is:

```
db.test.update(

  {
    "_id" : newID,  // QUERY
    "timestamp" : { "$lt" : newTimestamp }
  },
  { 
    "$set" : { "timestamp" : newTimestamp } // UPDATE
  },
  { upsert : true })
```

This works for all cases except for the case where an `id` already exists and the newTimestamp is older than the already stored `timestamp`. In this case, I get an `E11000 duplicate key error`.

How can I fix my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this might not be well explained or easily apparrent to notice, the methods such as `.update()` in the MongoDB shell ( and there is a move to make this the same for all drivers ) actually use the ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations API "under the hood".

This is a significant update to the "legacy" operations that existed before, not only in that there is "batch processing" of methods allowed, but also in the way the "writes" are committed and the response data given.

As a trivial example:

```js
> var date = new Date();
> db.testme.update({ "_id": 1 },{ "$set": { "updated": date } },{ "upsert": true })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 1, "nModified" : 0, "_id" : 1 })
```

Which returns a [`WriteResult`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/BulkWriteResult/#BulkWriteResult) Object displaying the statistics for what happened. In this case an "upsert" with the counter value and the "_id" of the document created.

In a second execution with the same `date` value you would get this:

```js
> db.testme.update({ "_id": 1 }, { "$set": { "updated": date } },{ "upsert": true })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Note the "nMatched" is `1` however "nModified" is `0`. This is because the API has the "smarts" to realize that no data was actually "changed" and there is therefore no modification made.

Of course if the date is changed to another value then a modification will occur:

```js
> var date = new Date();
> db.testme.update({ "_id": 1 },{ "$set": { "updated": date } },{ "upsert": true })
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

---

Expanding on that principle, "Bulk" operations are your friend in this case, where your logic is:

> *"Only modifiy the data where the new "date" is "greater than" the data present and only insert a new record where the _id value does not exist."*

The logic doesn't compound well into a single statement, however you can use "Bulk" operations to send both operations to the server at the "same time".

- One operation to try and modify under the conditions
- Another operation to attempt an upsert if the document does not exist

So it forms like this:

```js
    var bulk = db.testme.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    bulk.find({ "_id": 2, "created": { "$lt": date } })
        .updateOne({ "$set": { "created": date } });
    bulk.find({ "_id": 2 }).upsert().updateOne(
    { "$setOnInsert": { "created": date } });
    bulk.execute();
```

The additional help there is by [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) which will "only" make modifications to the matched document when "inserted" and not on a "match".

A first execution would be:

```js
var date = new Date("2015-07-03");

BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 1,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [
            {
                    "index" : 0,
                    "_id" : 2
            }
    ]
})
```

A second iteration with the same date:

```js
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

Indicates only one "match" on the second operation but no modification or upsert.

And changing the date backwards:

```js
var date = new Date("2015-06-03");

BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 1,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

Again only the second statement matched but no modification or upsert.

Changing the date forward:

```js
var date = new Date("2015-08-03");

BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 2,
    "nModified" : 1,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

Shows that both operations matched, however there was only "one" modification made which was from the first operation since `$setOnInsert` does not do anything where the `_id` value exists.

---

What you need are "two" statements to enforce your logic, but the Bulk Operations API allows you to send "both" to the server at once and also receive a single response.

Comment: Great answer! I'm actually trying to do this query via ReactiveMongo driver for Scala. There are some non-pretty native ways of doing Bulk inserts, for example using RawCommand... unless someone has something better?

Comment: @ShivanKaul For various "driver abstractions" the best case ( until there is better ) is to go "raw" and get the full functionality of the dirver. One of those cases where the raw driver offers more than the abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who stumbles across this and is trying to do a similar query in ReactiveMongo (like I was), based off of @BlakesSeven's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31198194/2989693), I did the following to run the query successfully in Scala:

```
val cmd = BSONDocument(
      "update" -> collectionName,
      "updates" -> BSONArray(

        BSONDocument(
          "q" -> BSONDocument(
            "_id" -> newId),
          "u" -> BSONDocument("$setOnInsert" -> BSONDocument("data" -> newData)),
          "upsert" -> true),
          BSONDocument(
          "q" -> BSONDocument(
            "_id" -> newId,
            "timestamp" -> BSONDocument("$lt" -> newTimestamp)),
          "u" -> BSONDocument(
            "$set" -> BSONDocument("data" -> newData)))
      )
    )

   db.command(RawCommand(cmd)) map (_ => // whatever)
```